# How to remember strategy that user was logged in?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have several strategies to authenticate to my app (twitter, google, ect.) I need to remember the strategy that user was logged in. Where is the best place to store it?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54d67c318ba5c79205c9ca00"
    },
    "facebook": {
        "id": "344435342",
        "token": "xxx",
        "name": "Erik",
        "email": "erik@google.com"
    },
    "twitter": {
        "id": "253452",
        "token": "xxx",
        "name": "Erik",
        "username": "ekir"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [User Profile](http://passportjs.org/guide/profile/) (`req.user`) contains a property

> `provider` {String}
>
> **The provider with which the user authenticated** (`facebook`, `twitter`, etc.).

---

As per our discussion in [the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/70488/2015/2/7) it seems you actually needed the access to `profile` which is available inside `function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {` of the passport authenticate function. You could then persist the `profile.provider` along with the user data model, or store it a session through the use of a [passport custom callback](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/).